# What is the proper way to print a nested list with the highest value in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a a nested list and I'm trying to get the sum and print the list that has the highest numerical value when the individual numbers are summed together

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
highest = list()

for i in x:
    highest.append(sum(i))

for ind, a in enumerate(highest):
    if a == max(highest):
        print(x[ind])
```

I've been able to print out the results but I think there should be a simple and more Pythonic way of doing this (Maybe using a list comprehension).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
print(max(x, key=sum))
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> print(max(x, key=sum))
[7, 8, 9]
```

This works because `max` (along with a number of other python builtins like `min`, `sort` ...) accepts a function to be used for the comparison.  In this case, I just said that we should compare the elements in `x` based on their individual `sum` and Bob's our uncle, we're done!

Comment: Thanks, it seems there's always a short and simple way of doing things in python

Comment: @danidee -- Not always, but frequently.  If there *isn't* a short, simple way to do it, then I usually take it as a warning to rethink what I'm trying to do to see if there might be a better way to design the feature that I'm working on.